# How to use the NotificationReciever in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to fire a block of code in my app whenever a notification comes in on Android, no matter what app. I learned that this is now possible via the Android 4.3 APIs introduced a while ago.  I found this [example](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/blob/master/NLSExample/src/main/java/com/kpbird/nlsexample/MainActivity.java) but my app can't resolve NotificationListener for some reason, I put in android-support-v4 into my libs folder and i have the proper imports. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try Using AccessibilityService, I hope it will solve your issue.
http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }
}
```

In Manifest Register like this:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
     </intent-filter>
     . . .
</service>
```

Comment: it should be in comment..not in answer.

Comment: @NoName Your answer is not proper solution.

Comment: this is just a link which should be in comment..its standard Stackoverflow rule. just follow them.